# Placement of a delete sql in a mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete records from a staging table in a stored procedure. I then need to insert records into the same table. This must be done prior to using a cursor that loops through the records.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Employee_Records()
BEGIN

DECLARE rollingSum INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE theMonth varchar(3);

-- Delete & insert on Employee must be done prior to the select 

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT Tgrowth,TYear,myMONTH FROM Employee;
         -- cursor body here
    CLOSE mycursor;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When i place my insert & delete statements in the commented section i get

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT Tgrowth,TYear,myMONTH FROM Employee' at line 63
```

Where would be the right place to place the insert & delete sql in the procedure. I could probably do this in a separate procedure but I want to know if i am missing something here.

Comment: Declarations first then code..

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There is no syntax error in the insert or delete statements. I have already created a second procedure for that. But I want to avoid that. Moreover I would have to call the second procedure from the first. That too needs to be done prior to the declaration of the select cursor. I am facing the same issue with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a begin...end block declarations must appear before any other code so
wrap the cursor section in a begin..end like so (btw you need to fix the code).

```
begin
    DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT Tgrowth,TYear,myMONTH FROM Employee;
         -- cursor body here
    open mycursor;
    CLOSE mycursor;
end;
```

There is almost never a reason to use cursors in sql - are you sure your approach is appropriate?

Comment: That works! For now that's the only approach i can think of. There probably is another way of doing what i want to do without cursors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with MYSQL but I think you DELETE and INSERT should come after Cursor declaration and and before opening and closing the cursor.